# Swagger $ref http responses

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swagger-editor

I am newbie to Swagger, and am working on API operations which create generic http response codes:-

- '401: Unauthorized
- '403':
         Forbidden
- '404':
        Not found
- '500':
        : Internal Server Error

I tried `$ref: #/definitions/responses` by defining responses but got an error. Is there a way to do this?, to avoid redundant block of code after each operation. Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found answer for this,

This can be done for referencing generic responses from some other file(in my case). Can be referenced from within a file as well.

```
 '400':
      $ref: _http-responses.yaml#/400
    '401':
      $ref: _http-responses.yaml#/401
    '403':
      $ref: _http-responses.yaml#/403
    '404':
      $ref: _http-responses.yaml#/404
    '500':
      $ref: _http-responses.yaml#/500
```

I created

> _http_responses.yaml

and then referenced it.